# Easy convergent sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence with $x_n > a \quad \forall \quad n \in \Bbb N $. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \ge a $.

Here's my attempt at a proof:

Let $x^*$ be the limit of $(x_n)$ as $n \to \infty$. Assume for a contradiction that $x^*<a$.  Then given an $\epsilon>0$, since $(x_n)$ is convergent, we have that $ \exists \quad N \in \Bbb N : \quad\left\lvert x_n-x^*\right\rvert<\epsilon \quad \forall \quad n \ge N $. By the negative triangle inequality, we have $ \left\lvert x_n \right\rvert-\left\lvert x^* \right\rvert < \epsilon \quad \implies \quad \left\lvert x^* \right\rvert > \left\lvert x_n \right\rvert - \epsilon \quad \implies \quad \left\lvert x^* \right\rvert > a - \epsilon $.

But it's at this point I get stuck: if the epsilon wasn't there, then I'd have a contradiction. Is proving this way salvageable i.e. am I missing an obvious step/trick or do I need to take a new direction? Thank you.

Comment: Almost done. $|x_n-x^*|<\epsilon \implies x_n-x^*<\epsilon$ because $x_n>a>x^*$. But $x_n-x^*<\epsilon \implies x_n<x^*+\epsilon$ which is impossible when $0<\epsilon <(a-x^*)/2$ because it makes $x_n<a.$

Comment: @user254665 A bit of a side question, so have we basically done a contrapositive proof here? i.e. we've taken the negation of $ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \ge a $ and shown it implies the negation of $ x_n > a $ ?

Comment: A good way to handle limits is that  $(\lim x_n=x^*)\iff $  (Whenever $ U$ is a neighborhood  of  $x^*$,  the set  $ \{n :x_n\not \in U\}$  is finite)......   In particular $\forall e>0 \; \{n: x_n\not \in (x^*-e,x^*+e)\}$  is finite, so there certainly exists $ n$  with  $x_n\in (x^*-e,x^*+e)$.

Comment: yes the proof is by contradiction, that $x^*<a$ is untenable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary to your advantage: pick $\epsilon = a - x^* > 0$. Then for $n$ large enough, we have $|x_n - x^*| < a - x^*$, which implies that $x_n < a$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One quick question, how come you are allowed to take away the modulus signs like that? What if $x_n-x^*$ is negative?

Comment: @mathphys In general the inequality $|b| < c$ is equivalent to $-c < b < c$. In this case, we have $x^* - a < x_n - x^* < a - x^*$, and we only need the second inequality.

Comment: @mathphys Or, put differently: if $x_n - x^*$ is negative, it is for sure smaller than $a - x^* > 0$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. A quick side-question: am I correct in saying we've done a contrapositive proof here? I say this because it seems that we've taken the negation of $ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \ge a $ and shown it implies the negation of $ x_n > a $. But then again, is $ x_n < a $ really the negation of $ x_n > a $ or is $ x_n \le a $ truly the negation?

Answer (score 2):

You can maneuver to find a smart $\epsilon$. This amounts to, by contradiction, proving that your sequence is inside a place it shouldn't be. This approach is done by @A.P.

But you can use the fact that you've found an inequality which holds for every $\epsilon$, and there is no sequence in it anymore. It is an inequality of real numbers. Since this is an ubiquitous strategy, I'll spill out the details.

You've found that $|x|^*>a-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Hence,
$$\epsilon>a-|x|^*$$
for all $\epsilon>0$. This makes you conclude that $0\geq a-|x|^*$. Why? Because if this was not the case, then $ a-|x|^*>0$ and you would be able to plug in $a-|x|^*$ in the other side, leading us to
$$a-|x|^*>a-|x|^*.$$
This seems like the "same thing" as proving what the exercise asks (and can be seen as a consequence), but it is a more basic fact, easily justifiable as seen above. Not only that, it is an strategy that helps in a lot of situations. You show that something holds for every epsilon, then you can conclude an inequality with it.

Comment: Ah that's pretty neat. So basically, from $0 \ge a - \left\lvert x^* \right\rvert $ we can conclude that $ \left\lvert x^* \right\rvert \ge a $ as required? And if I did it using your continuation, I wouldn't even need my assumption for a contradiction from the beginning since at no point have we used it here, right?

Comment: @mathphys Yes, and yes! If you want to see an example where this kind of situation arises, you can look up the proof that the diameter of the closure of a set is the same as the diameter of the set.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that the limit inferior of a real sequence is its smallest limit point.

---

**Edit:** Let me elaborate more on this. Recall that the *limit inferior* of a real sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ is defined to be

$$\liminf x_n := \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{k\geq n} x_k\right) = \sup_{n\geq 1} \left(\inf_{k\geq n} x_k\right).$$

Here the last equality follows from that $\{\inf_{k\geq n} x_k\}_n$ is an increasing sequence.

One nice aspect of the notion of limit inferior is that we don't require the sequence to be convergent for it to be meaningful (unlike the notion of limit). We also have that the limit inferior of a real sequence is the smallest sublimit of that sequence (see pp. 56-57 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, 3e). In particular, if a sequence is convergent, then it has a unique sublimit, so that the limit inferior and the limit of the sequence will coincide.

Finally we have the following argument:

\begin{align}
&\forall n: x_n > a\\
\implies &\forall n, \forall k\geq n: x_k > a\\
\implies &\forall n: \inf_{k\geq n} x_k \geq a\\
\implies &\sup_n\inf_{k\geq n} x_k \geq a\\
\implies &\liminf x_n \geq a
\end{align}

Observe that this argument holds for any sequence bounded from below by $a$. If in addition $\{x_n\}_n$ is convergent, then by the above remark $\lim x_n\geq a$.

Comment: You may want to show how your hint can finish off the proof. What I would recommend is to spoiler hide the rest of the steps so that the original poster can look at them to know you have a complete proof with your method. Right now, it seems like the people who downvoted cannot get the rest of the proof, or think you should finish the proof off.

Comment: Thanks Element118 for the explanation, I appreciate it! If only the people who cared enough to downvote would also care to explain why they downvoted. To me the downvotes are unfair, because I am not pretending to provide a full answer and what I suggest is nothing more than using the definitions, and hence is more elementary. I am also suggesting a different approach as well, one that proceeds directly. Hence I am confident I am making a contribution to this thread.

Comment: This of course makes sense before I edited my answer.